# Background Images with Content Using Responsive Design

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to get my head around background images within responsive design. In this example page (http://test.scoe.net/rfox/usalResponsive6/indexTeacher5.html), I have a large photo with some text and a few buttons overlaying it. I've taken great care to position and size the text and buttons at specific window widths: full screen, 1024px, 768px, 640px, 480px and 320px. At those widths, the layout looks reasonably good. It's the in-between sizes where things go astray. Things look ok at the larger sizes, but once I drag my browser window smaller, around 760px, the image itself starts to scale and I get large gaps between it and the next item below it. Any suggestions on an approach to take to keep it looking decent across different widow sizes?

Comment: can you please share your code?

Answer (score 1):

That's a good start.

The problem is that the space allotted for text becomes smaller and smaller as the viewport becomes smaller. In your example link, seeing the hero at under 480px, the text only has ~165px width to work with because you're using percentages and so it starts to look awkward.

I suggest to swap out the background image for another that allows for more space for the text container. The bg image functions as contextual information anyway, and your text is your true content.

Your text container really should be almost 100% for anything below 480px. For an example that may be similar to yours, see https://fi.google.com/signup how their initial paragraphs only occupy the left, but as your scale downward, the text container spans across.

In your code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    .zTchrBlurb-xs visible-xs {
        width: 90%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this, Phil. So when you say "100% for anything below 480px," do you mean that the text should take up the entire width of the viewport at <480px?

Comment: Yup, with some breathing room of course. I think the operating principle is "content is king." On mobile, because of limited space, if you can remove as much obtrusion as possible, it makes your site more readable and accessible to your mobile readers. This is especially relevant with smaller phones. 

Also, there are best practices for how many characters/line you should have. So that changes when you scale down to mobile. See: http://www.motocms.com/blog/en/mobile-typography-best-practices/

Comment: Thanks for the link and the link to the article on best practices. Much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem as well in the past, 
you could change background position to cover and adjust accordingly, but personally I found this library here - invaluable.

https://johnpolacek.github.io/imagefill.js/

One approach I took in the past working with background images that needed to scale:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 100%;
background-size: cover;
width: 100%;
height: 260px;
```

Comment: Interesting code, nykc. I'm not sure how it would work with my image though. Is the center of the image always kept in the center of the viewport, is that what this does?

Comment: It may be a bit overkill from what you need to accomplish, I ran into an issue where I had basically a grid of images that needed to be responsive, this library would rescale and keep the image aspect ratio. I am not 100% sure it will completely solve your issue - but it is one option. 

I am going to edit my initial answer with what I did in a similar situation with a background image.